# 0-1 knapsack implementation using dynamic programming

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

It is working fine for the given value of weight, value, max_weight and total_items but it is giving segmentation fault when I change the weight, value and other variables.

I checked that when i am changing the variables then in knapsack function `items->value` and `items->weight` becomes `NULL`.

And `items->max_weight` and `items->total_items` becomes `0`.

I can't figure out what is wrong in my code, please help, thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int total_items, max_weight;
    int *weight, *value;
} Items_knapsack;


void knapsack(Items_knapsack *items, int solution[][items->max_weight + 1]);
int max(int a, int b);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int max_weight = 7, total_items = 4;
    int weight[] = {0, 1, 3, 4, 5};
    int value[] = {0, 1, 4, 5, 7};

    Items_knapsack items = {.value = value, .weight = weight, .max_weight = max_weight, .total_items = total_items};
    int solution[total_items + 1][max_weight + 1];

    knapsack(&items, solution);

    for ( int i = 0; i < total_items + 1; i += 1 )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < max_weight + 1; j += 1 )
        {
            printf("%d ", solution[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}

void knapsack(Items_knapsack *items, int solution[][items->max_weight + 1])
{
    int total_items = items->total_items;
    int max_weight = items->max_weight;

    for ( int *i = (int *) solution; i < &solution[total_items + 1][(max_weight + 1)]; i += 1 )
    {
        *i = 0;
    }

    for ( int i = 1; i < total_items + 1; i += 1 )
    {
        for ( int j = 1; j < max_weight + 1; j += 1 )
        {
            int w = *(items->weight + i); //weight of current item
            int v = *(items->value + i); //value of current item

            if ( w > j )
            {
                solution[i][j] = solution[i - 1][j];
            }

            else
            {
                solution[i][j] = max(v + solution[i - 1][j - w], solution[i - 1][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: On which line does it fault? Which values are known to work and which cause a fault?

Comment: I can't even get your code to compile.

Comment: @jwdonahue it is compiling on gcc.

Comment: It's err.. .'not exactly clear', 'total_items = 4;'....'int weight[] = {0, 1, 3, 4, 5};'  what's with the weightless item, and those loops with pointers and indices starting at 1?  Sorry, too messy for me.  I suggest that you put in the values that fail and hit it with your debugger.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valgrind reports:

```
==8563== Invalid read of size 4
==8563==    at 0x108977: knapsack (17640299.c:53)
==8563==    by 0x108831: main (17640299.c:23)
==8563==  Address 0x4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

This is in the loop:

```
    for ( int j = 1; j < max_weight + 1; j += 1 )
    {
        int w = *(items->weight + i); //weight of current item
        int v = *(items->value + i); //value of current item
```

(I'm not sure why those are not written as the more-readable `items->weight[i]` and `items->value[i]` respectively).

I re-wrote the method to be clearer to read, and could no longer trigger this failure:

```
void knapsack(const Items_knapsack *items,
              int solution[items->total_items+1][items->max_weight + 1])
{
    const int total_items = items->total_items;
    const int max_weight = items->max_weight;

    for (int i = 0;  i <= total_items;  ++i)
        for (int j = 0;  j <= max_weight;  ++j)
            solution[i][j] = 0;

    for (int i = 1;  i <= total_items;  ++i) {
        const int w = items->weight[i]; //weight of current item
        const int v = items->value[i]; //value of current item

        for (int j = 1;  j <= max_weight;  ++j) {
            if (w > j) {
                solution[i][j] = solution[i-1][j];
            } else {
                solution[i][j] = max(v + solution[i-1][j-w],
                                     solution[i-1][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. This was my second question on stackoverflow. First question led me to study the basics of gdb. Now going after your valuable suggestions I am going to study gdb in more detail and also valgrind.